# Issue with FullText or LIKE search (unable to find inventory)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, full-text-search, sql-like

Having some trouble finding an item in my inventory when a user searches for something that I know is in the inventory.

Table Columns are ManufacturerNameMatch, SubCategoryNameMatch, MainCategoryNameMatch, Model_Name

When I search Nikon Ti-E the script can't seem to find it. However, I know that it's in the inventory. In the database the Model_Name is listed as "Eclipse Ti-E w/HUBC Inverted Phase Contrast" and the ManufacturerNameMatch is 'Nikon'

I'm using FullTextSearch Index for multiple word searches, but that can't seem to find it so I've been messing with concatenating the columns and using a LIKE search (still nothing). Wondering if someone has some better ideas, or what I'm doing wrong or not understanding with FullTextIndex searches or LIKE searches with MySQL.

```
$category = 'Nikeon Ti-E'
$findPhraseMatch = DB::table('inventory')
                                ->selectRaw(DB::raw("*, GROUP_CONCAT(CambridgeID) as `CambridgeIDArray`, count(*) as `groupTotal`"))
                                ->where(DB::raw("CONCAT_WS(' ', ManufacturerNameMatch, SubCategoryNameMatch, MainCategoryNameMatch, Model_Name)"), 'LIKE', "%$category%")                                   
                                ->where('Units_OnHand', '>=', 1)                                    
                                ->groupBy('Model_Name', 'ManufacturerNameMatch')
                                ->orderBy('ManufacturerNameMatch')
                                ->paginate(15);
```

FullText Search here

```
// $final would look like +nikon +ti+e
$findFullMatch = DB::table('inventory')
                        ->selectRaw(DB::raw("*, GROUP_CONCAT(CambridgeID) as `CambridgeIDArray`, count(*) as `groupTotal`"))
                        ->whereRaw("MATCH(ManufacturerNameMatch, SubCategoryNameMatch, MainCategoryNameMatch, Model_Name, Title_Override, Description_Old) AGAINST ('$final' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND Units_OnHand >= 1")
```

Comment: Are you aware that this query will run only under certain sql mode settings because you have fields in the select list that are neither in the group by clause, nor are subject to an aggregate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `like` operator cannot find what you are looking for this way, since the concatenated text do not contain `Nikeon Ti-E` substring. There is also a spelling mistake, but this may only be misspelled here on SO.

You would have to search for `like '%Nikon% Ti-E%'` (note the additional % between Nikon and Ti-E) if you wanted to use the `like` operator.

Using fulltext search may be a more adequate solution for this. I would use the [Boolean mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html), in which you can specify that both words should be in the concatenated content in order to be present in the results.

```
... where match(ManufacturerNameMatch, SubCategoryNameMatch, MainCategoryNameMatch, Model_Name) against ('+Nikon +"Ti-E"' in boolean mode)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I'm also using a fulltext search directly above and for whatever reason I can't seem to return this item in the inventory. I've edited my original post to include the fulltext search. Any ideas?

Comment: thanks for the response. The solution I found was to enclose the entire string in double quotes along with a + in front of every word. So I am splitting a users search and adding a + in front of each word and adding double quotes around the entire string. Seems to be working. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Yes, you need to use the " as I did around words that contain certain characters, such as -. If the above response helped you to resolve the issue, then pls mark it as accepted, so other viewers of this question will know that it is closed.